# Debezium MongoDB Connector Error: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

I am trying to deploy a new Debezium Connector for MongoDB with Transforms. The configuration looks like this:

```
{"name": "mongo_source_connector_autostate",
    "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector", 
    "tasks.max":1,
    "initial.sync.max.threads":4,
    "mongodb.hosts": "rs0/FE0VMC1980:27017", 
    "mongodb.name": "mongo", 
    "collection.whitelist": "DASMongoDB.*_AutoState",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type" : "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope",
    "transforms.sanitize.field.names" : true
    }}
```

However the connector fails with the following error:

```
 org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:290)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:316)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:240)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal initial character: 10019_AutoState
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.validateName(Schema.java:1528)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.access$400(Schema.java:87)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$Name.<init>(Schema.java:675)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.createRecord(Schema.java:212)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectSchema(AvroData.java:893)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectSchema(AvroData.java:732)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectSchema(AvroData.java:726)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectData(AvroData.java:365)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:80)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:62)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$2(WorkerSourceTask.java:290)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
        ... 11 more
```

I have started the connector in distributed mode with the following configuration:

```
...
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
...
```

Note: I have another connector without any transforms. It runs just fine.

I would like to get some help regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your fields seems to be violating the Avro naming rules. In your case it seems to be this one:

> The name portion of a fullname, record field names, and enum symbols
>   must:
>
> - start with `[A-Za-z_]`

But `10019_AutoState` violates the rule as it starts with numerical values. You can change it to something like `AutoState10019`

---

You can view the full list with all the record field naming constraints [here](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#names).

Comment: Thats right! My collection name unfortunately starts with a number and we cannot change it.

Comment: @NilabhraPatra Unfortunately I don't think there is a workaround.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thank you :)

Comment: There is a workaround but requires witing a Java code. You can introduce a Single message transform that will rename the schema before it gets into converter,

Answer (score 1):

What Debezium version? If it is problem with 1.1/1.2 then please raise a Jira issue. The schema name needs to be sanitized an it seems to me that in this case the error comes from collection name `10019_AutoState` and the schema name not sanitizied as it must not start with number.

Comment: I am using version 1.1.

Comment: Could you please report this as a bug in ebezium then? Thanks

Comment: I have created DBZ-2046 for this.